# What is a Vector3 Normal and Point for the RayCollision in raylib?

Tags: c++, raylib

I am trying to use the RayCollision struct for collision, My Game is basically flappy bird. I am basically trying to get the collision between the "pipe" and the "bird" using raylib.

Here is my Code lines - 202 - 209
https://gitlab.com/1NEGROUP/crappyturd2/-/blob/main/rayWindow.cpp

```
typedef struct RayCollision{
bool hit;
float distance;
Vector3 point;
Vector normal;
}RayCollision;
```

[image]

I need a coding example please

I have tried to make this my self using the point and normal but i really have no idea what i was doing and anytime i was trying to get collisions the bird was colliding with itself

Comment: Are you using C? The shown `typedef struct RayCollision` is invalid in C++: `'typedef ': ignored on left of 'RayCollision' when no variable is declared` or `typedef requires a name`.

Comment: i am using the raylib.h file which has the code exactly as shown and i have no issues with declaring and using the RayCollision struct in c++. What i have issues with is understanding what a Vector3 Normal and Point is for getting the collisions correct

Comment: No, the shown code is not exact as in raylib.h https://github.com/raysan5/raylib/blob/master/src/raylib.h#L428-L433 Your question is too broad. Show your code.

Comment: Your right i think i had an issue with copy and paste I put my code up there. How is my Question to broad?